# Use a matrix to inform where pixels should be on or off (Numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I am not sure how to word this. I am sure there is an operation that describes what I am trying to do I just don't have a lot of experience manipulating image arrays.

I have a 2D array (matrix) of 1s and 0s which specify if a group of pixels should be the color [255,255,255] or the color [0,0,0] in rbg. It seems like this should be a simple multiplication. I should be able to multiple my color by my matrix of 1s and 0s to make an image, but all the dots products and matrix multiplication I have tried has failed.

Here is a simple example my 2D numpy array and

```
# 2D pixels array
[[0,1],
 [1, 1]]

# rbg array
[[255,255,255]]
```

What I would want is the following 3D array

```
[[[0,0,0],[255,255,255]],
 [[255,255,255], [255,255,255]]]
```

This array has the shape 2X2X3.

Here are the arrays for reproducibility and to make it easy for anyone willing to help.

```py
pixel = np.array([0,1,1,1]).reshape(2,2)
rgb = np.array([255,255,255]).reshape(1,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about reshaping pixel into a 3D matrix and using dot?

```
pixel = np.array([0,1,1,1]).reshape(2,2,-1)
rgb = np.array([255,255,255]).reshape(1,3)
pixel.dot(rgb)
```

Output

```
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are multiplying matrices element-wise, they must be broadcastable, meaning that numpy can convert their size into a common size. From [the numpy documentation:](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting)

> Broadcasting can be understood by four rules:
>
> 1. All input arrays with `ndim` smaller than the input array of largest `ndim`, have 1’s prepended to their shapes.
> 2. The size in each dimension of the output shape is the maximum of all the input sizes in that dimension.
> 3. An input can be used in the calculation if its size in a particular dimension either matches the output size in that dimension, or has value exactly 1.
> 4. If an input has a dimension size of 1 in its shape, the first data entry in that dimension will be used for all calculations along that dimension. In other words, the stepping machinery of the [ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html#term-ufunc) will simply not step along that dimension (the [stride](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#memory-layout) will be 0 for that dimension).

Your desired dimension structuring boils down to a three-dimensional array, where the dimension indices have the meaning `(y coordinate, x coordinate, colour channel)`, where the colour channel index is either `0`, `1`, or `2` (for red, green, and blue, respectively).

To abide by the rules shown above and get the desired dimension structuring explained above, we need to ensure that our `pixel` array has three dimensions, of which the third dimension can have size `1` (see rule 3). The `rgb` array can stay the same, as dimensions will automatically be added at the front (see rule 1). Because of rule 2, the resulting array will take the size of the `pixel` array for the first two dimensions, and the size of the `rgb` array for the third dimension.

To add a third dimension to the `pixel` array, you can either use `reshape` (as the other answers show), or the [`expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) function. Then, you can simply do an elementwise multiplication between the arrays, and numpy will automatically broadcast the arrays using the rules discussed above. See the following example:

```
>>> pixel = np.array([
...     [0, 1],
...     [1, 1]
... ])
>>> rgb = np.array([255, 255, 255])
>>> pixel.shape
(2, 2)
>>> rgb.shape
(3,)
>>> pixel = np.expand_dims(pixel, axis=2)  # add a third axis to get the correct shape
>>> pixel.shape
(2, 2, 1)
>>> image = rgb * pixel
>>> image.shape
(2, 2, 3)
>>> image
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]]])
```

Note that numpy prints the array a bit differently than you might expect, but you can simply verify that the array matches your desired array:

```
>>> image[0, 0, :]
array([0, 0, 0])
>>> image[0, 1, :]
array([255, 255, 255])
>>> image[1, 0, :]
array([255, 255, 255])
>>> image[1, 1, :]
array([255, 255, 255])
```

Answer (score -1):

When multiplying matrices, the columns of the first matrix must match the rows of the 2nd matrix. And the Rows of the first matrix and column of the 2nd matrix will be the new dimension of your result.

An example is if you have a 1x3 matrix and you multiply by a 3x4 matrix. this is a valid multiplication since the first matrix has 3 columns and the 2nd matrix has 3 rows. The result will then be a 1x4 matrix due to the first matrix having a single row, and the 2nd has 4 columns.

For your example I think you need a nested loop to multiply each element in your pixel array with the RBG values. I don't know a great way to do this, but I think this may work.

```
pixel = np.array([0,1,1,1]).reshape(2,2)
rgb = np.array([255,255,255]).reshape(1,3)

arr = np.zeros((2,2,3))

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(3):
            arr[i][j][k] = pixel[i][j] * rgb[0][k]
```

Comment: There is no need to create a nested loop and skip all numpy vectorisation optimisation. As an indication, this loop implementation is 8.6 times slower on my machine than a vectorised implementation for the 2×2 image, and this increases to over 150 times slower for a random 1000×1000 image.